# How to detect an empty int input?

Tags: c++, input

I am trying a coding Q and am looking for a line of code that detects if there was no input given (user just presses enter). The concerned datatype is int.

I've read few other Qs about this very problem, but didn't fit in well with my needs. I have tried eof & other such suggestions to no avail...

Here's the code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int ogv,cgv=0,i,j=0,k;
int arr [3];
vector<int> ans;
while(true) {
    cgv=0;
    cin>>ogv;
    //if("ogv is not a number, just an enter") 
          break;
    arr[0]=floor(ogv/4);
    arr[1]=floor(ogv/3);
    arr[2]=floor(ogv/2);
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++) {
        if (arr[i]<0)
            arr[i]=0;
        cgv+=arr[i];
    }

    if(ogv>cgv) {
        ans.push_back(ogv);
    }
    else {
        ans.push_back(cgv);
    }
   j++;
}
for(k=0;k<j;k++) {
    cout<<ans.at(k)<<endl;
}
}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated...! :D

Thanks

Comment: my be get char using getch() function is good for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [noskipws manipulator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noskipws/)

Example:

```
int x = -1;
cin>>noskipws>>x;
if(x==-1)
{
    // no number was entered, the user just pressed enter
}
else
{
    // the user entered a number
}
```

---

EDIT: In order to use this in a loop, you need to discard the characters that are currently in the buffer before each read attempt.

For example, if the user inputs the number 4 and presses enter in the first iteration of the loop, cin will read the 4, but it will leave the end-of-line character in the buffer. When the read occurs in the second iteration, cin will see the end-of-line character in the buffer and it will treat it as if the user pressed enter, exiting the loop.

We can use the [`sync()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/sync/) method in order to discard any unread characters in the buffer. We need to do this before any attempt to read from `cin`:

```
cin.sync();
cin >> noskipws >> x;
```

Comment: It works, but partially. The program quits only after the first iteration. Any fixes? Maybe its because it doesn't go to the next line for the input. Any idea how to take it to the next line? Thanks...

Comment: When you read a number, there is an end-of-line character that is left in the stream, and that is treated as if the user pressed enter the next time the read is attempted. You need to ignore the characters that are currently in the buffer before each attempt to read. In order to do that, you can use the [sync()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/sync) method before each read, like this: `cin.sync()`. I tested it in your program, and it works.

Comment: Awesome dude! I however, had to use **cin.ignore()** instead of cin.sync(). Thanks a lot...

Comment: I think you should use `sync()`. If you use `cin.ignore()` (with no arguments), it will ignore at most 1 character, until it reaches an end-of-line character. If the user enters more that 1 character, it will only ignore the first character. So, for example, if the user enters "7 ⏎" (seven, a space and an enter-EOL), then cin will read seven, ignore() will ignore the space, and the EOL will remain in the buffer, and the loop will exit the next iteration. If you use `sync()`, you won't have this problem, because sync() ignores everything that is in the buffer.

Comment: I understand the risk, and would preferably use `sync()` rather than `ignore()`. But as it turns out, `cin.sync()` or `sync()` makes the program exit after the very first iteration...

Comment: That's weird... I have tried it in your program, and it works for me. Here is the code I am using: [http://pastebin.com/C2jwCPDq](http://pastebin.com/C2jwCPDq) and the output when I run the program: [http://imgur.com/tYxMi](http://imgur.com/tYxMi)

Comment: I just copied and pasted the code into my compiler, and received the same results as before. Weird enough. I think it may be a compiler specific issue. I'm running an updated NetBeans IDE using the cygwin compiler... Thanks a lot for your help, mate...! :D

Comment: You're welcome. That may be the cause... I am using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: was getting `'noskipws' : undeclared identifier`, had to use `std::noskipws` with a namespace

Answer (score 0):

If you use streams to input an integer, it will skip white space before reading it in. That includes any amount of newline characters you may enter.

In other words:

```
int i;
std::cin >> i;
```

won't return until it finds some non-whitespace.

If you want to detect an empty line, I usually just use `getline` to get a complete line into a string, then string streams to convert that to an integer, something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main (void) {
    std::string s;
    int i = -1;

    std::cout << "Enter string: ";
    std::getline (std::cin, s);
    std::cout << "String is '" << s << "'\n";

    std::stringstream ss (s);
    ss >> i;
    std::cout << "Integer is " << i << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Transcript follows:

```
pax> ./qq
Enter string: 
String is ''
Integer is -1

pax> ./qq
Enter string: hello
String is 'hello'
Integer is -1

pax> ./qq
Enter string: 0
String is '0'
Integer is 0

pax> ./qq
Enter string: 1
String is '1'
Integer is 1

pax> ./qq
Enter string: 314159
String is '314159'
Integer is 314159
```